# Capturing Picture with OpenCV and Arducam Camera

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I have this very small python script that is supposed to take a picture with the `Arducam` camera that is attached to the Raspberry Pi. However the picture that it saves is just all black.

```py
import cv2

def take_picture(file_path):
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    if not camera.isOpened():
        print("error: could not open camera")
        return

    ret, frame = camera.read()

    if not ret: 
        print("error: failed to capture image")
        return

    cv2.imwrite(file_path, frame)
    camera.release()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_path = "image.jpg"
    take_picture(file_path)
    print(f"picture taken and saved as {file_path}")
```

I have tried changing the `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` to -1 and other indices and the script doesn't save an image at all. With `cv2.VidoeCapture(0)` it does save an image but it's all black. I have a similar script that does the same thing but shows the live footage in a pop out window but that script also just has a black feed. If anyone has any ideas as to why the camera takes black images it would be very helpful.

Comment: Your code is working. Using Bullseye and Bookworm. It saved filename too.